# Bitrise Xamarin Build Configurations in multiple submodules / projects

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, bitrise

I have an app for ios and android written in Xamarin which I am trying to build with Bitrise.

In the platform project I have 10 build configurations for different releases of the app. In the two submodule projects I have simply a debug & release configuration (and debug|iPhone & simulator on the ios project) - these projects don't need to know about which release of the app is going out - the build config's are for resources and manifest/plist details.

In the solution I use configurations mappings to specify what build config should be used for the submodule projects, i.e.

Solution Configuration : Release_a_particular_version
Platform project maps to : Release_a_particular_version
Core project maps to : Release
Submodule Library maps to : Release

This builds fine in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio but when building in Bitrise gets an error, project configuration not found.
If I create configurations in both submodules with the same name as the solution_configuration everything builds well.

I imagine there's an msbuild switch to turn configuration mapping on? If there is, how would I apply that to the bitrise build step?

Or some alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your **Bitrise configuration** and the **failed build log**, it is hard to answer this question.

To help you, we would need to take a look on your configuration and on the failed build log.

You can reach out our support team on Bitrise on-site-chat (on every Bitrise page you can find a message icon in the lower right corner where you can send us a message).